# Question regarding the proof of Lemma 5.35 in Joy of Cats

Tags: category-theory

Before going into the main problem, let me just write down the relevant definitions for the sake of completeness.

> **Definition 1.** Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a category. A concrete category over $\mathbf{X}$ is a pair $(\mathbf{A},U)$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a category and $U : \mathbf{A} \to \mathbf{X}$ is a faithful functor.
>
> **Definition 2.** If $(\mathbf{A},U)$ and $(\mathbf{B}, V)$ are concrete categories over $\mathbf{X}$ , then a concrete functor from
>   $(\mathbf{A},U)$ to $(\mathbf{B}, V)$ is a functor $F : \mathbf{A}\to \mathbf{B}$ with $U = V \circ F$. We denote such a functor
>   by $F : (\mathbf{A},U)\to (\mathbf{B},V)$.
>
> **Definition 3.** A concrete functor $F$ between two concrete categories $(\mathbf{A},U)$ and $(\mathbf{B}, V)$ over $\mathbf{X}$ is said to be a concrete equivalence if $F:\mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{B}$ is an equivalence.
>
> **Definition 4.** A concrete category $(\mathbf{A},U)$ over $\mathbf{X}$ is said to be transportable provided that for every $\mathbf{A}$-object $A$ and every $\mathbf{X}$-isomorphism $UA \overset{k}{\to}X$ there exists an $\mathbf{A}$-object $B$ with $UB = X$ such that $A \overset{k}{\to}B$ is an $\mathbf{A}$-isomorphism

In [Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) at page 73 the authors provide the proof of the following proposition (number unchanged),

> **LEMMA 5.35**. For every concrete category $(\mathbf{A},U)$ over $\mathbf{X}$, there exists a transportable concrete category $(\mathbf{B}, V)$ over X and a concrete equivalence $E : (\mathbf{A},U)\to (\mathbf{B}, V)$.

In the proof of the theorem they define the category $\mathbf{B}$ as follows:

> Each $\mathbf{B}$-object is a triple $(A, a, X)$, with $A \in Ob(\mathbf{A}),
> X \in Ob(\mathbf{X})$, and $a : UA \to X$ an $\mathbf{X}$-isomorphism. For each $(A,a,X),(\hat{A},\hat{a},\hat{X})\in Ob(\mathbf{B})$ the $\text{hom}$-sets are defined as follows,
>   $$\text{hom}_{\mathbf{B}}((A, a,X), (\hat{A},\hat{a},\hat{X})) = \text{hom}_{\mathbf{A}}(A,\hat{A})$$
>   Identities and composition are as in $\mathbf{A}$.

However, strictly speaking, by the definition of a category of the book (see Def. 3.1, page 21), $\mathbf{B}$ is not a category since the $\text{hom}$-sets are not disjoint. Although by Remarks 3.2(3) we do not need to show that $\text{hom}$-sets are not disjoint.

But I was wondering, is it possible to modify the definition of the category $\mathbf{B}$ in such a way that the proof goes through and the $\text{hom}$-sets become disjoint?

Comment: Remark 3.2(3) doesn't just tell you why we don't care if hom-sets are disjoint, it also gives you a construction for turning any non-homset-distjoint-category into a category proper. You can do that for this concrete example, too.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Sure. But how then the proof goes through? I am stuck with showing that the resulting category (under this new definition) is also transportable.

Comment: There should be no essential differences in the proof.

Comment: @Berci: Can you give at least a hint/outline as an answer?

Comment: @user170039 It's hard to know what kind of a hint could help, because the construction of 3.2(3) gives you a category which is *isomorphic* as a category-without-disjoint-homsets, so this is a bit like asking for a hint about how to prove $2+2=4$ for one set-theoretical definition of $2$ as opposed to another. The proofs are exactly the same.

Comment: Regarding your concluding question, note that $id_A$ is not denoting an identity morphism in $\mathbf B$ here, since $(A,a,X)\neq (A,f\circ a,Y)$. So it is not correct that $f$ is the identity of $V(A,a,X)$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: $id_{A}$ is surely a $\mathbf{B}$-morphism here. Are you trying to say that $id_A : (A, a,X) \to (A, f \circ a, Y )$ is a $\mathbf{B}$-isomorphism but not an identity morphism because $(A, a,X) \neq (A, f \circ a, Y )$?

Comment: @user170039 Yes, that is what I said.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Now it really feels silly for me to even ask the second question. I am removing that part.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: If the $\text{hom}$-sets are not disjoint then what is the definition of equality of two morphisms, say, for $id_A:(A,a,X)\to (A,f\circ a,Y)$ and $id_A:(A,a,X)\to (A,a,X)$?

Comment: @user170039 In a category with non-disjoint homsets one should never ask whether two morphisms are equal unless they are known to have the same domain and codomain, which is the only case in which equality of morphisms has any meaning. Depending on the foundations, it may be that equality is still *defined*, say if the collection of all morphisms is to constitute a set whose elements are all sets, but it may also be that the equality is not even defined.